# Lotus Notes - How to update lastname on Lotus Notes 9 or 8.5 login drop down list

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a user who requested her last name to be updated on Lotus Notes.  I went to her lotus notes profile and updated her last name and username but still when she tries to login to Lotus Notes, her username (firstname lastname) on the drop down list still show her old lastname.

Any thought on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a description how to rename a user in Notes/Domino: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_RENAMING_A_USER_AUTOMATICALLY.html

Comment: I have already checked that before asking here

Comment: Did you just checked it or did you rename her this way including running Adminp for changing her name everywhere?

Comment: Yes I renamed according to that link but still unchanged

Comment: It looks like the renaming process needs time to be completed throughout the entire system

Answer (score 1):

What's in a name? In Lotus Notes and Domino, it is much more than a string of characters.

Domino comes with a built-in Public Key Infrastructure enabling a two-factor authentication.

This means that a name change :

1. Must be certified by the relevant Certification Authority
2. Must also happen in the authentication factor the user has on her own workstation, namely a file name like .id or user.id

The correct procedure is for Kurt's comment.
It is a bit complex, and it does require that at some point the user take an action to accept her new name.

Depending on your organization's topology (how many Domino servers there are and how they are connected) the change can be effective in minutes or take up to a few hours.

Now, if you have custom applications, brace for the following. Depending on how those applications were designed and administered, the change may or may not propagate to pre-existing documents, which means that the user may lose access to some of her stuff. If that's the case, check the application's Access Control List, on the Advanced tab, the "Administration Server" box.

Comment: How to update the name on the ID file that the user has on their workstation?

Comment: That is automatically provided for by Domino. At some point, the user is delivered an email where the id update is attached. That's where she can accept of refuse.

Other options depend on if, and how, your organization stores the users ids files. In well-kept houses it's in the form of the [ID Vault](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/12162008022843PMNEKQT7.htm). Some punks simply stash them on a drive. At any rate, at that point, you take it to a thumb drive and walk to the workstation.

Comment: Other options depend on if, and how, your organization stores the users ids files. In well-kept houses it's in the form of the [ID Vault](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/12162008022843PMNEKQT7.htm). Some punks simply stash them on a drive. At any rate, at that point, you take it to a thumb drive and walk to the workstation.

Comment: I am not trying to replace the ID File (that is ez). I am just trying to change the last name on the system

Comment: Just confirmed with the user that the name has been changed.  All what needed to be done is to go to Domino Admin --> Search for the user --> go to rename under tools -> choose change common name --> enter psw --> update the name.  The waiting time to update the name depends on how big the system is.